# angular filter:{v:0} does not filter anything. Other values work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, filter, ng-options

For some reason this simply does not filter anything.

Here is the selection:

```
<select
    ng-model="s.id"
    ng-options="c.v as c.name for c in oarray | filter:{v:0}"
>
</select>
```

This is structure:

```
$scope.oarray = [{ name:"(select)", v:0 },{ name:"name1", v:100 },{ name:"name2", v:200 }];
```

The select box lists all elements: `"(select)"`, `"name1"`, and `"name2"` even though filter says to return only `"(select)"` for it is the only one with the member `v==0`.

If I change filter to `v:100` it will filter the stuff properly.

Why?! If this is a 'feature' or a 'side effect' then what would be the workaround without changing already predefined values?

Thank you in advance.

PS: Here is your playground: http://plnkr.co/edit/huRPv08A4bucJmcG60Fe?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is searching for all objects where the value for v *CONTAINS* `0`, not where it equals `0`.

You need to send `:true` to the filter to tell it to do a strict comparison, eg

```
ng-options="c.v as c.name for c in oarray | filter:{v:0}:true"
```

The second parameter here is the comparator, an optional parameter that defaults to `false`. The [Angular documentation for filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) contains the following information about this parameter:

> Comparator which is used in determining if values retrieved using
>   expression (when it is not a function) should be considered a match
>   based on the the expected value (from the filter expression) and
>   actual value (from the object in the array).
>
> Can be one of:
>
> `function(actual, expected)`: The function will be given the object
>   value and the predicate value to compare and should return true if
>   both values should be considered equal.
>
> `true`: A shorthand for `function(actual, expected) { return
>   angular.equals(actual, expected)}`. This is essentially strict
>   comparison of expected and actual.
>
> `false`: A short hand for a function which will look for a substring
>   match in a case insensitive way. Primitive values are converted to
>   strings. Objects are not compared against primitives, unless they have
>   a custom toString method (e.g. Date objects).
>
> Defaults to `false`.

Comment: Uh, oh! Thank you so much!